# Mod Rewrite routing/loading all files if condition is correct

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I want to achieve is loading static files from a subfolder for mobile users with a htaccess contidion.

If user_agent=mobile then load /mob/*.html else load *.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|... (list is very long)
RewriteRule ^$ /mobile/$ [R,L]
```

Alternatively I also look at Apache AMF, but they have example for redirecting to m.domain.com, whereas I want to load static files from a subfolder. By the way, I don't want to show /mobile/ in the address bar. I want to block direct access to /mobile/*.html files too.

http://wiki.apachemobilefilter.org/index.php/Mod_rewrite_integration

Comment: Do _not_ use the explicit `R` flag in your rule, it makes an _external_ redirect, so it changes the URL shown in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture value in `RewriteRule` and use it a back-reference to it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}(android|bb\d+|meego).+(mobile|avantgo|bada/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine)
RewriteRule ^((?!mobile/).*)$ mobile/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I get internal server error 500. This is all on my htaccess. Do I have any other errors? Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com\.au$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop .. etc) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mobile/$1 [L]

Comment: Now it works for domain root, I mean .com.au/, but not .com.au/test.html . This time no error, but it loads desktrop version on /*.html

Comment: No that's not right. On my Apache it works fine for `domain.com.au/test.html` also

Comment: It is apache 2.4, Centos7x64. I will check on another server.

Comment: It worked on Centos6 box. Is it apache configuration related issue?

Comment: I checked apache configuration on that box, it seems I added some extra lines to that server to solve some htaccess settings. Now it is solved. Thank you very much!